# How to automatically evaluate a cell and then jump to a specified location

Tags: front-end, notebooks, customization

I built a new word bank of many words myself. I hope that every time I open this notebook `nb` file, this cell can run automatically, so that I can automatically assign a value to `newwords`, and then automatically make cursor jump to the cell of the query content.

[image]

```
newwords={"abate", "abbreviate", "aberrant", "ability pump", "abound", \
"abrade", "abrogate", "abscess", "abstain", "abstinence", "abstruse", \
"abut", "academician", "accede", "accessory", "accommodate", \
"accordion", "accredit", "accreditation", "acid", "hyper", \
"acidosis", "acne", "acquaint", "acquisitive", "acrophobia", \
"acropolis", "acumen", "acupuncture", "adamant", "adduce", "adept", \
"adjunct", "admonish", "admonition", "adobe", "adolescence", "adore", \
"adorn", "adulterate", "advent", "adversity", "adz", "aerobic", \
"aesthetic", "afferent", "affiliate", "affinity", "affluent", \
"afterlife", "ageism", "agile","..."};
SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], Next, CellContents, 3(*跳转次数*)]
```

[image]

```
Select[newwords, 
 StringMatchQ[#, 
   "obli" ~~ __] &](*After executing the cell above, I want to jump \
to this cell automatically (this cell does not need to run \
automatically)*)
```

[image]

I want to achieve this function by modifying the cell expression of the cell where `newwords` is located, but how can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming they are consecutive cells you can do:

```
(*make sure this cell does not produce output because then NextCell is the output cell*)
newwords = {...};
selectCell = NextCell[];
SelectionMove[selectCell, Before, CellContents];
NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "\"", Next, CellContents];
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, Character];
```

```
Select[newwords, StringMatchQ[#, "obli" ~~ __] &]
```

Seems to do what you need.

Side note, consider `Iconize` for `newwords` or even move them to a separate .m file and `Get` it.